# Access pandas dataframe column with two header pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe using `groupby` and `pd.cut` to calculate the mean, std and number of elements inside a bin. I used the `agg()`and this is the command I used:

```
df_bin=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.In_X, ranges,include_lowest=True)).agg(['mean', 'std','size'])
```

df_bin looks like this:

```
                 X                  Y
                 mean   std size   mean         std  size
In_X                    
(10.424, 10.43] 10.425  NaN  1      0.003786    NaN   1
(10.43, 10.435] 10.4    NaN  0      NaN         NaN   0
```

I want to create an array with the values of the `mean` for the first header `X`. If I didn't have the two header level, I would use something like:

```
mean=np.array(df_bin['mean'])
```

But how to do that with the two headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation would serve you well: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

To answer your question, if you just want a particular column:

```
mean = np.array(df_bin['X', 'mean'])
```

But if you wanted to slice to the second level:

```
mean = np.array(df_bin.loc[:, (slice(None), 'mean')])
```

Or:

```
mean = np.array(df_bin.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean']])
```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. Your solution takes the mean values from both X and Y main headers

Comment: Oh I misunderstood.  If you just want the 'X' then `mean = np.array(df_bin['X', 'mean']) `would work already.

Comment: Worked great. Perhaps, I should open a new question. But how do know how to use `dropna()` to drop only the rows where the mean of X is NaN?

Comment: You could always apply `dropna()` directly `df_bin['X', 'mean']` before you pass into array.  `mean = df_bin['X', 'mean'].dropna().values`

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df_bin.stack(level=0)['mean'].values
```