# dropna ( ) in multi-header dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dataframe using `groupby` and `pd.cut` to calculate the mean, std and number of elements inside a bin. I used the `agg()`and this is the command I used:

```
df_bin=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.In_X, ranges,include_lowest=True)).agg(['mean', 'std','size'])
```

df_bin looks like this:

```
                 X                  Y
                 mean   std size   mean         std  size
In_X                    
(10.424, 10.43] 10.425  NaN  1      0.003786    NaN   1
(10.43, 10.435] 10.4    NaN  0      NaN         NaN   0
```

I want to drop the rows of only when I encounter a NaN case. I want to create a new df_bin, without the NaN occurrences. I've tried:

```
  df_bin=df_bin['X', 'mean'].dropna()
```

But this drops all other columns of df_bin and keep only one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try pull all the `mean` out, find the null

```
df_bin=df_bin_temp[df_bin_temp.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'mean']].notnull().all(1)]
        X                Y       
        m   s  i         m   s  i
0  10.425 NaN  1  0.003786 NaN  1
```

Or we do

```
df_bin=df_bin_temp.dropna(subset=df_bin_temp.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'m']].columns)
        X                Y       
        m   s  i         m   s  i
0  10.425 NaN  1  0.003786 NaN  1
```

Comment: @sammywemmy do small change from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740537/copying-multiindex-dataframes-with-pd-read-clipboard

Comment: I've asked a question in this sense today, please have a look here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965631/access-pandas-dataframe-column-with-two-header-pandas/61965685?noredirect=1#comment109597610_61965685

Comment: @YOBEN_S I was using  `dropna()` with a regular dataframe before, now for the multiindex dataframe I used your first suggestion and it is quite faster. Thanks!